# QBFC: Customer Mobile Number is nothing?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I am looking te retreive the Mobile Number for a customer.

QBFC has a .mobile property on the ICustomerRet interface.

This property however, does not get set, and returns nothing...?

Inspecting the OSR, I don't see the mobile property in the Response mapping. (But it is in the QBFC intellisense)

Inspecting the qbXML returned, I see the data I am looking for is in fact in the xml, here...

```
<AdditionalContactRef> 
<ContactName>Mobile</ContactName> 
<ContactValue>xxxxxxxxx</ContactValue> 
</AdditionalContactRef>
```

There are other additionalContactRef xml tags for many other properties, Inc. Main Phone, Alt Phone, Main Email etc.

I reckon I probably have to look to retrieve it here, but it seems like the QBFC framework is missing this functionality?

Inspecting the `.AdditionalContactRefList` , to try and step through it, I don't see the ContactName and ContactValue properties on it. Only `.Fullname`, `.ListID` and `.Type`.

I would appreciate some insight on this?

Regards

Comment: What version of QBFC are you trying to use?

Comment: Version 12, I presume. Latest SDK / QBFC, with Quickbooks Enterprise 13.

Answer (score 1):

The Mobile field for a ICustomerRet is only available when using the Online version of QuickBooks. In the OSR at (https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html), there is a column that shows which edition(s) the field is available in. You are seeing it in intellisense as QBFC is a wrapper for all editions, so it is included if you were interfacing with Online.

Keep in mind that what version of QuickBooks you are using may also have an effect on what fields are available. You can adjust the slider on the OSR to indicate what version you are calling. Even though you are using the version 12 SDK, you can call an earlier version when creating your IMsgSetRequest.

```
// Create a request for QuickBooks using SDK version 9
IMsgSetRequest request = SessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 9, 0);
```

Comment: Had a similar issue and this saved my bacon